# arquivo envia para a pasta, mas não envia os dados para o banco

Tags: php, mysqli

Eu upei um site para um servidor, fazendo todas as configurações necessárias, eu tenho o controle de galeria que tem um arquivo upload que envia os dados para a pasta e as informações para o banco, nada fora do normal, porém o problema é que do jeito que fiz, apenas esta enviando os dados para a pasta e não para o banco... O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Segue o bloco de código que tentei até agora:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES)){
require 'conn/conn1.php';
 $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir.$fileName;

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetFilePath)){
        $insert = $conn1->query("INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$fileName."', NOW())");
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: O que falta é tratar o erro que possivelmente está acontecendo no *INSERT*, e pra isso existem N formas. Se a sua conexão for em PDO, já dá pra extrair alguma informação colocando este pequeno trecho depois do INSERT: `var_dump($conn1->errorInfo());`.

Comment: obrigado, descobri o problema, estava na estrutura da tabela no banco, mas obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel, uma alternativa é você gerar um nome único para o arquivo, e no banco de dados apenas inserir o nome do arquivo. Dessa forma, ao utilizar por exemplo `<img src="caminho/nomedafoto">` você consegue resgata-lá. Seria algo do tipo:

```
$nome_imagem = md5(uniqid(time())) . ".jpg" ; //extensão de exemplo
$caminho_imagem = "uploads/" . $nome_imagem;
move_uploaded_file($imagem["tmp_name"], $caminho_imagem);
$insert = $conn1->query("INSERT INTO files (file_name, uploaded_on) VALUES ('".$nome_imagem."', NOW())");
```